# Click of Edit button not changing the html on the page after table filter

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a button that when clicked should switch my html from 'Add New User' to 'Update User' elements. Currently it works when the table has not been filtered. After I have done any sort of filtering on the table, the Edit button no longer works.

**Add New User Div**

```
<div id="addNewUser" class="newUser" style="border: solid black 2px">
//snip
</div>
```

**Update User Div**

```
<div id="update_User" class="updateUser" style="border: solid black 2px">
//snip
</div>
```

**Edit User Button**

```
<td><button id="@user.UserId" class="updateUser" value="@user.NtUserId">Edit</button></td>
```

**Show add/edit jquery**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('div.updateUser').hide();
            $('button.updateUser').click(function () {debugger;
                $('div.updateUser').innerHTML
                $('div.updateUser').show();
                $('div.newUser').hide();
            });
        })
    </script>
```

Comment: What you are trying to do with `$('div.updateUser').innerHTML`?

Comment: What kind of filter are you using? Are you removing and re-adding them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your table filter might be removing and re-adding elements to the DOM hence try to bind your click event to the document instead of the specific element;

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   $('div.updateUser').hide();
   $(document).on('click','button.updateUser',function(){ //document does not require quotes
      // $('div.updateUser').innerHTML
      $('div.updateUser').show();
      $('div.newUser').hide();
   });
});
```